# What are some tips/tricks to garage door lubrication?

Tags: lubrication, garage-door

Are there any gotchas to garage door lubrication?

I have found the [Prime Flo product](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100313097/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) on Home Depot's website.

Can I lubricate the large spring at the top of the garage door? What about the garage rails? What about the rail from the garage opener that makes it all work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The rail from the garage door should be lubricated with White Lithium Grease, whether it's a chain or a screw type. Run a bead of grease along the top of it, then run the garage door up and down a few times.

The wheels, track and spring should be lubricated with your favorite lubricant oil -- not WD-40, which is a cleaner and penetrant, not a lube -- but an actual lubricant. I think I usually use [silicone liquid wrench](http://www.liquidwrench.com/products/#!/2).

If the garage door still does not operate, check the alignment of your tracks to make sure they aren't binding. The spring might need to be re-tensioned, which is NOT (in my opinion) a DIY project.

Comment: just to clarify, the chain/screw it exposed on the bottom. How do I squirt grease in there to prevent from falling on the garage floor?

Comment: It's usually exposed both on the top and bottom -- get on a ladder and take a look. If not, the white lithium grease is more like toothpaste than a spray -- just shove the tip in there and squeeze it out.

Comment: Karl:  Right on. perfect advise.  @OAOD:  white lithium grease applied with the small tube on the side of the spray can will stick and work in, not leak or drop down unless you get carried away and put way too much on.

Answer (score -1):

Don't lubricate the roller tracks.  Only lubricate the moving parts and the top of the rail.