# Is it OK to use powdered graphite to lubricate a garage door opener?

Tags: maintenance, lubrication, garage-door-opener

I am about due to lubricate my garage door opener and related parts, and while I have some silicone lubricant, I was wondering if I could be doing better.

The can I have says it's good for all parts (springs, tracks, rollers, chain and screws), but lately, I've heard about powdered graphite as a highly effective lubricant, and was wondering, since it's safe for extreme temps and bonds to a variety of materials, if it would be safe to use on any or all parts of my garage door system?

Comment: Do you have chain or screw door opener?

Comment: See also: [What are some tips/tricks to garage door lubrication?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/8011/22)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Powered graphite will be very messy.  I still recommend spray on white lithium grease or garage door lube from PB Blaster.  Both products are great for the chain, rollers, and roller channels.  Never use WD 40 or any type of oils.